# optimal control -Taylor expansion - PDE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, control-theory, perturbation-theory

I am trying to follow perturbation analysis in this paper (Optimal control of fluid limits of queuing networks and stochasticity corrections) and I am stuck at one point.

For the given control problem, HJB eq. is defined as follows:

$\displaystyle (\lambda - \mu_1)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} + (\mu_1 - \mu_2)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2} + c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 =0$

However, the author then defines ( in the context of perturbation analysis) by Taylor expansion:

$\displaystyle G_1 V + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}G_2 V + \frac{\epsilon^3}{6}G_3 V .. +  c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2=0$

Then comes the part that I am confused about:

$\displaystyle G_1 = (\lambda - \mu_1)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1} + (\mu_1 - \mu_2)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}$

and $\displaystyle G_2=(\lambda + \mu_1)\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial x_1^2} + (\mu_1 + \mu_2)\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial x_2^2} - 2 \mu_1 \frac{\partial v^2}{\partial x_1 x_2} $

I do get that $G_1 $is first order approximation but I have no idea how $G_2$ is derived the way it is. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Amzoti sorry it is a typo - for \mu.

Comment: no problem, was just an observation. Are the signs on $G_2$ correct? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti yes, they are. I don't get how they are computed!

Comment: What is the relation between $V$ and $v$? Do you have to have different powers of $V$ in the Taylor expansion?

Comment: @gerw Actually V is defined as follows: $v(n1,n2) =\epsilon^{-1}*V(x1,x2)$. And I realized that epsilon's have powers as well, I edited the question, sorry about that.

Comment: What is $n1$, $n2$? Is there a relation to $x1$, $x2$?

Comment: @gerw Well n's and x's are fluid levels in Queue 1 and Queue 2. As far as I understand, we want to compute $V(x_1, x_2)$ but it is unknown. We then propose a change of variables to $n_1, n_2$ and then do the taylor approximation.